# flutter_admob how to integration with IOS swift

Tags: flutter, admob

I'm trying to implementation flutter_admob to show "native ads" in IOS swift but only I found example in Object-c!!
is there any way to implement it in swift code without use any package else

Comment: Do you mean examples for native ads?

Comment: yes but in swift